# Swift Ambiguous use of sum()

Tags: swift

I have the following extension:

```
protocol Addable {

    init()

    func + (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self

}

extension Int: Addable {}
extension Double: Addable {}

extension SequenceType where Generator.Element: Addable {

    func sum() -> Generator.Element {

        return reduce( Generator.Element() ) { $0 + $1 }

    }

}
```

Which I try to use in a unit test:

```
func testThatArrayOfDoublesCanCalculateTheSumOfAllElements() {

    let numbers = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]        

    let myExpectedValue = 1.0 + 2.0 + 3.0

    let myActualValue = numbers.sum()

    XCTAssertEqual(myExpectedValue, myActualValue)

}
```

[image]

In Xcode 7.3 the compiler gives me a *Ambiguous use of 'sum()'*. Why?

The side panel says:

[image]

Comment: What is `numbers`?

Comment: Assuming `numbers` is an array of `Int`s or `Double`s I can't reproduce this compiler error.

Comment: Updated my test case.

Comment: The use of sum() is ok in the same module as the extension is declared, but an error in the test module. If I add public keyword to the extension it is an error also in the module where the extension is declared.

Comment: Your last remark suggests that you have a conflicting definition of sum() somewhere in your code. Inspect the compiler output (in the Report navigator), it should show why it is ambiguous.

Comment: Strange it says that build succeeded, No issues. But at the same time showing two issue symbols. (One for my use of sum() in the same module as the extension declaration and one for the use of sum() in my test case.) This is when the extension is declared public.

Comment: @weenzeel: Lookup the full compiler error message in the Report navigator and post it as text here.

Comment: /Users/Erik/Desktop/_libraries/AFTechnicalAnalysis/AFTechnicalAnalysisTests/AFTechnicalAnalysisTests.swift:37:29: error: ambiguous use of 'sum()'
        let myActualValue = numbers.sum()
                            ^
<unknown>:0: note: found this candidate
/Users/Erik/Desktop/_libraries/AFTechnicalAnalysis/AFTechnicalAnalysis/Extensions.swift:24:10: note: found this candidate
    func sum() -> Generator.Element {
         ^

Comment: Thanks Martin for your help. Found my solution. Se answer. Happy weekend!

Answer (score 4):

The problem was that I was building my Extension file both in my framework target and my test target.